# Do mobile games have only one ad that they toggle on off throughout the entirety of the game?

Tags: android, libgdx, admob

I am adding ads to the game I am making and I was wondering how it works? Do you have multiple ads each set to a specific part of the game i.e Menu, Pause, Store and whatnot? Or do they have one ad which they toggle on if the user is in the menu and off when the player is playing the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it really matters and more depends on your app.

For me and my libgdx game, I just have a single style of ad across the whole app.  It is just a basic banner that I used over and over and over again in the same style whenever I need it.  This is even easier for games as often the whole game (main screen, game screen, pause etc) is all rendered on one canvas so you only need one android layout for the entire game.

However, you might have different formats/sizes of ad in different places - e.g. a 320x50 on the main game screen but an interstitial on the menu page.  If this were the case I'd go for separate ad units for each style of ad.